# Java -> разработка своей функции, принимающей предикат

Tags: java

Итак, задался задачей расширить функционал ArrayList, дабы научить его находить элемент по предикату(да-да, привет C#). Но как назло по запросам в гугл выдает только "Новые фичи в java 7\8" и т.п.
Прошу покидать информации по поводу сабжа, или привести конкретный вариант такой реализации(функция с приемом аргумента и объяснение, как эта функция динамически получит T у объекта листа).

Comment: Т.е. функция должна принимать элемент массива и возвращать boolean?

Answer (score 5):

Ну если 8ая java, то там есть сам предикат как таковой. Создаем из списка stream, фильтруем его посредством [предиката](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html), и формируем результат в список.

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "one", "two");
List<String> result = lines.stream()                
            .filter(line -> !"one".equals(line))     
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Вот [тут](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-filter-examples/) еще примерчики есть.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш метод должен принимать один из функциональных интерфейсов. Т.е. интерфейс, в котором есть ровно один нестатический метод.

Список стандартных функциональных интерфейсов можно найти [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html)

Вам нужен интерфейс `Predicate<T>`. У него есть метод `test(T t)` который принимает объект параметризированного типа `T` и возвращает `boolean`.

Полный код получится таким

```
class CustomArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
  public int customIndexOf(Predicate<T> pred) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
      if (pred.test(get(i))  // Проверяем, наш ли элемент?
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

И использование

```
CustomArrayList<Integer> list = new CustomArrayList<>();
........
int idx = list.customIndexOf((val) -> val % 5 == 0);
```

Найти первый элемент, делящийся на 5

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    public Optional<E> findFirst(Predicate<E> predicate) {
        for (E item : this) {
            if (predicate.test(item))
                return Optional.of(item);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

MyArrayList<Integer> list = new MyArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);

Optional<Integer> item = list.findFirst(i -> i == 2);
```